# How to restart a process inside a container / Restarting PhpStorm using original restart.py

Tags: python, docker, phpstorm

I'm making an image with PhpStorm (as a part of my effort to build  portable development environment). Everything runs pretty smoothly except that PhpStorm can't restart itself. It uses `bin/restart.py` script for that purpose which doesn't work when dockerized.

This is the body the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Waits for the parent process to terminate, then executes specified commands.

import os
import signal
import sys
import time

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    raise Exception('usage: restart.py <pid> <path> [optional command]')

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)

pid = int(sys.argv[1])

while os.getppid() == pid:
    time.sleep(0.5) // ***

if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    to_launch = sys.argv[3:]
    os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, to_launch[0], to_launch)

to_launch = ['/usr/bin/open', sys.argv[2]] if sys.platform == 'darwin' else [sys.argv[2]]
os.execv(to_launch[0], to_launch)
```

The script runs up to the line marked with `***` — i.e. immediately after the parent process exits.

I tried to run PhpStorm with `bash` root process, as well as with [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) or [TINI](https://github.com/krallin/tini) processes without any difference.

Any ideas what's going wrong and how to "fix" this? Is there some specific signal which must be implemented in the root process or it's a nature of docker which disallows for such uses?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem is to restart the container, which is the point of putting a process inside a container in the first place.

Comment: It's not a solution as PhpStorm restart wouldn't work.